# Pros/Con of Excel VBA v SQLite

Tags: sqlite, excel, vba

I am recently working with a relational database program that has been written in Excel VBA. Excel VBA was chosen as it is a default application on computers where I work and therefore everyone would be able to use the database.

As part of the database development the need has arisen to add some more tables which will only interact programmatically with the current database. In order to consider all my options I am contemplating separating this new data either as an SQLite or second excel file.

I keep changing my mind as to what would be the best route and would appreciate information from those who work with the programs.

The new database would need to perform normal database functions quickly and efficiently. Given this context what are the advantages/disadvantages of using SQLite compared with excel?

Answer (score 0):

Excel is not a database! If you want to use the Office applications, use Access, it is designed for that.

If you want to use SQLite, bear in mind that there is no concurrency. So if PC1 writes to the database, and PC2 wants to do that too, the file is locked by PC1 and you will get an error on PC2.

**My recommendation:**
You can also install SQL Server Express, this is free, **with a few terms** (10 concurrent users & max 10GB db). And then store your data in your SQL server. Use Excel as an interface to collect data from the SQL Server in your Excel/VBA applications. This is a lot more scale-able then Access, let alone SQLite.

OR: If your organization doesn't allow installation of software or whatever reason, go for Access.

You can use SQLite if you have a single application on a single device. Think about mobile apps, they use SQLite for example. If you have two applications on a single device, the concurrency problem of SQLite comes around the corner. It is possible that both apps want to **write at the same time**, which will give you an error.

Comment: I agree with you completely Excel is not a database unfortunately a substantial amount of coding has already been done using it. Given changes will not be made concurrently, am I right in thinking that no installation is required to use SQLite from VBA? The company computers do not automatically have Access installed either.

Comment: Correct, you can download SQLite, extract the package, and start using it without the need to install anything if you get the DLL's. Try https://sqliteforexcel.codeplex.com